# How do I use an ember component in more than one ember application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two different ember applications, but a specific subsection of both will be absolutely identical. I would much prefer, moving forward, to edit a single source of truth for this functionality, and then plug it into both applications whenever it is changed.

What would be a way to accomplish this?

I would assume there is a way to simply plug in the components themselves or, barring that, building another ember app and embedding it in the larger app. Either solution, or another solution, would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about building and distributing applications, rather than about Ember *per se*.  I would first define the shared code in a `namespace`: (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Namespace.html) and then wrap that up as a node.js module, with a `package.json` file that describes the module.

Then, I would use `bower` to install the package by specifying the module in the `bower.json` dependency section.  (http://bower.io/)

This approach gives you more control over your development of all three products- two applications and a shared framework.  It then allows you to version your shared code so you don't have to upgrade both applications at the same time-  Quite a few problems solved by leveraging the package management features of bower.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, which actually has much less to do with ember itself, is to have a common place to retrieve files for you applications.  Such as a CDN url that you can hit for common libraries, images, global files etc.  It seems as thought you may be trying to have the same file locally in two places, and have both update whenever you make changes to one common place.  This could also be achieved by simply having a symlink to that file in each project.

Either way, your solution will probably be a server action than it will be an actually Ember issue.

Hope this helps.